# ES6 Set comparison and get duplicate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Assume there are 4 ES6 Set for 4 sets of data

```
state = {
    aSet: new Set().add(1).add(2).add(3).add(4).add(5), // 1,2,3,4,5
    bSet: new Set().add(2).add(3).add(4).add(5).add(6), // 2,3,4,5,6
    cSet: new Set().add(3).add(4).add(5).add(6).add(7), // 3,4,5,6,7
    dSet: new Set().add(4).add(5).add(6).add(7).add(8)  // 4,5,6,7,8
}
```

Now I want to compare these 4 ES6 Set and get the duplicate (4,5) to form a new Set.

Any suggestion??

Comment: you mean if `aSet` has the number 4, and if `bSet` has the number 4 as well, put 4 in a `eSet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the set *intersection* principle to do this.

By going over each `Set` in the `state` using `Array#reduce` we compare the old `Set` from the previous iteration with the new `Set` in the current iteration and only return the intersection of the two.

The first iteration does no comparison as it takes the first set as the starting point:

```js
const state = {
  aSet: new Set().add(1).add(2).add(3).add(4).add(5), // 1,2,3,4,5
  bSet: new Set().add(2).add(3).add(4).add(5).add(6), // 2,3,4,5,6
  cSet: new Set().add(3).add(4).add(5).add(6).add(7), // 3,4,5,6,7
  dSet: new Set().add(4).add(5).add(6).add(7).add(8) // 4,5,6,7,8
}

const intersection = (sets) => {
  return sets.reduce((prevSet, nextSet, idx) => {
    if (idx === 0) return nextSet;
    return new Set([...nextSet].filter((e) => prevSet.has(e)));
  }, new Set());
}

const sets = Object.values(state);
console.log([...intersection(sets)]);
```

Comment: Thanks ☺️ Good explanation

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```js
const state = {
  aSet: new Set().add(1).add(2).add(3).add(4).add(5), // 1,2,3,4,5
  bSet: new Set().add(2).add(3).add(4).add(5).add(6), // 2,3,4,5,6
  cSet: new Set().add(3).add(4).add(5).add(6).add(7), // 3,4,5,6,7
  dSet: new Set().add(4).add(5).add(6).add(7).add(8) // 4,5,6,7,8
}


let intersection = new Set([...state.aSet].filter(x => state.bSet.has(x)&& state.cSet.has(x)&& state.dSet.has(x)))

intersection.forEach(value=>console.log(value))
```

There's a good article that walks you through the various options you have for comparing sets (intersection, union etc):

[Comparing sets](https://medium.com/@alvaro.saburido/set-theory-for-arrays-in-es6-eb2f20a61848)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const aSet = new Set().add(1).add(2).add(3).add(4).add(5); // 1,2,3,4,5
const bSet = new Set().add(2).add(3).add(4).add(5).add(6); // 2,3,4,5,6
const cSet = new Set().add(3).add(4).add(5).add(6).add(7); // 3,4,5,6,7
const dSet = new Set().add(4).add(5).add(6).add(7).add(8); // 4,5,6,7,8

const allSet = new Set([...aSet, ...bSet, ...cSet, ...dSet]);

const result = [...allSet].reduce((acc, elm) => {
  if (aSet.has(elm) && bSet.has(elm) && cSet.has(elm) && dSet.has(elm))
    acc.add(elm);
  return acc;
}, new Set());

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Intersection example from: https://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-set-operations.html

```js
const state = {
    aSet: new Set().add(1).add(2).add(3).add(4).add(5), // 1,2,3,4,5
    bSet: new Set().add(2).add(3).add(4).add(5).add(6), // 2,3,4,5,6
    cSet: new Set().add(3).add(4).add(5).add(6).add(7), // 3,4,5,6,7
    dSet: new Set().add(4).add(5).add(6).add(7).add(8)  // 4,5,6,7,8
}

const intersection = (a, b) => new Set([...a].filter(item => b.has(item)));
const intersections = (object) => Object.values(object).reduce(intersection);

console.log(Array.from(intersections(state)).join(', '));
```